# Transistors to use for eight voltage sweeps from two PWM Arduino pins

Tags: pwm, current, voltage

On my Arduino Mega, there are two PWM pins open. There are eight analog voltage inputs to a datalogger. They are connected through a PCB, and I need test them with a DC voltage sweep. (There are many boards, so that is why I'm making a testing device instead of manually doing each with a variable power supply.)

As an analogy, it's like using four DMMs to measure the the same +Vcc to see if each DMM works.

Is some sort of amplifier circuit needed to output a maximum of 5 V to the eight datalogger inputs? Is an external power source needed? Please give me some direction.

The DC sweep does not have to go to 5 V. For what it's worth:

```cpp
for(int s = 51; s < 256; s += 51)
{           // PWM: 255 = 5V
  analogWrite(analogWpin, s);      // sweeps thru 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5 V
  delay(500);
  analogWrite(analogWpin, 0);
  delay(500);
}
```

---

Related

- [Connecting many RGB LEDs to same PWM pins?](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=9880.0)
- [Controlling multiple pc fans with single pwm pin](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=478598.0)
- [Controlling multiple fans using arduino uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/50134/controlling-multiple-fans-using-arduino-uno/)
- [Multiple DC motors from 1 pwm](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=85982.0)

Comment: Can each analog input can have the same value, or is it necessary to give different voltages to each input? Do you need to test them at the same time?

Comment: There is a module with the AD5669. It is a 8-channel 16-bit dac. Adafruit and sparkfun have a MCP4725 module, a 1-channel 12-bit dac, perhaps there is a way to use eight of those.

Comment: @chrisl It's just sweeping each with the same increasing value. It doesn't have to happen at the exact same time. All the test is doing is showing if the PCB is all connected correctly and functioning properly.

Comment: @AdamUraynar then you still can not keep the other channels open/unconnected. To detect a shortcut between channels, you still need to connect the other channels to, for example, 0v/gnd. A dac + mux is not enough.

Comment: So the AD5669 module would be similar in function to adding another Arduino Mega (6 pins + previous 2 to output the analog voltage).

Comment: `analogWrite()` does *not* create an analog voltage (I *hate* that function name!). It creates a PWM signal. To make it an analog voltage you have to add some signal conditioning to filter out the carrier frequency.

Comment: Ok. As long as you understand it that's fine.

Comment: There are many 8 channel (sometimes called "octal") dac chips. For example the AD7228. If a conversion from pwm to analog is no problem, then you can try software pwm, or use a dedicated extra arduino board with software pwm. For exampe a cheap arduino nano clone with: https://github.com/Palatis/arduino-softpwm